# Reset ChangeNotifier Values when re entering a page Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am making a quiz app. Once I submit a quiz and come back to the same page I want all the values to have been reset.

I have found that this is because when I open the page the first time a new ChangeNotifier object is created but if the user comes back to the page it just reuses the same one. I would like to delete and create a new one or reset the original.

Here is my ChangeProvider

```
class ARVariables with ChangeNotifier {
  int questionnumber = 0;
  bool submitted = false;
  List<int> selectedanswers = List.filled(_questions.length, -1);
  List<int> scores = List.filled(_questions.length, 0);
  List<int> unselectedanswers = [];
  List<int> intervals = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20];

  // some methods here
}
```

I ideally would like something like either be able to modify the ARVariables object in the initState or delete the object when leaving the page so that a new one is made upon load.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about creat new function to reset inside of ARVariables class.

```
void reset (){
questionNumber = 0;
submitted = false;
//(same conditions for other variables)
  }
```

And then call this function before popup page after submit.